# Left side of screen glTranslatef

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

If you write `gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -10.0f);` your object appears in the center. I can change it to `gl.glTranslatef(-2.0f, 0, -10.0f);` and it will move to the left, but is it possible to generate that x value automatically, so it would be on the left for all devices the same? Because I guess if I write `gl.glTranslatef(-6.0f, 0, -10.0f);` and it looks good on my screen on the left, it will probably be not good on bigger or smaller devices.

P.S. Maybe I should get width or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on the type of view your using, for:

```
GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 67, glGraphics.getWidth()
                / (float) glGraphics.getHeight(), 0.1f, 10f);
```

and for

```
gl.glOrthof(0, WORLD_WIDTH, 0, WORLD_HEIGHT, 1, -1);
```

i think that they stretch the parameters that you specify in them to every device the same